# Is it possible to dynamically add one more super class in existing class

Tags: class, lisp, common-lisp, clos

In Common-Lisp CLOS

Is it possible to dynamically add one more super class
in existing class.

Update:

I wanted to defined **defassoc** kind of macro that will associated some behaviour
with method/function using same argument

e.g.

```
(defassoc (gname (s (g group)))
    ((name1 (name ((corresponding-task task g) s)))
     (record1 (record ((corresponding-task task g) s))))
  (let ((n name1)
        (r record1))
    (if (and name1 record1)
        (display name1 record1)
        (call-next-method))))
```

expand to

```
(symbol-macrolet ((name1 (name ((corresponding-task task g) s)))
                  (record1 (record ((corresponding-task task g) s))))
  (defmethod gname :after (s (g group))
            (let ((n name1) (r record1))
              (if (and name1 record1)
                  (display name1 record1)
                  (call-next-method)))))
```

Here it is ensuring when ever (gname (s (g group)) is call
here should be call for corresponding task to group

```
(name ((corresponding-task task g) s)
(record ((corresponding-task task g) s)
```

I used this macro

```
(defmacro defassoc ((main-method main-method-lambda-list)
                    funspec-list &body body)
  `(symbol-macrolet ,(mapcar (lambda (fspec)
                               (destructuring-bind (name f) fspec
                                 (list name f)))
                             funspec-list)
     (defmethod
       ,main-method ,mod ,main-method-lambda-list
       ,@(if body
             body
             `(if (and
                   ,@(mapcar (lambda (e)
                               (car e))
                             funspec-list))
                  (call-next-method)))))
```

But problem is that it will overwrite the

```
(defmethod gname :after (s (g group))
      ...)
```

(If it has any, I can verify it if it has one or not,)

**But I want it to work for any object whether it has that method to overwrite or not**

So basically it should be needed to change in code for any thing in that classes and methods.

So one way I decided that to dynamically add parent class to define this method on it.

Other way could be **defadvide** or **fwrapper** but it is not present in SBCL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. The easiest way would be to simply redefine the class. You do that by issuing another call to `DEFCLASS`. If you want to do more complicated things, you have to resort to the MOP (MetaObject Protocol). Essentially everything you'd ever want to do is possible using the MOP, but I would need more detailed information as to what it is you're trying to do in order to explain it further.